# Category Theory Texts as Complement to Algebra Course

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose someone is reading something at the level of Knapp’s **Basic Algebra**, and they know the basic objects of Algebra: groups, rings, but not quite yet fields, would it be a good time to pick up a Categorical Text? If so, what Category Theory book would you recommend?

Comment: "The book on category theory" would be "Categories for the working mathematician" by Saunders MacLane, although that is quite abstract. A better option may be "Category Theory" by Awodey, which is also intended for non-mathematicians.

Comment: I would recommend Leinster’s Basic Category Theory before Riehl as Riehl’s text is more difficult and more terse (more in the style of conventional textbooks). It’s a great *follow-up* read but Leinster provides  a more gentle, yet still informative, introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick up a category theory text book at any time, do not let people tell you otherwise. I would not read most of the very old category theory texts, since they are not very beginner friendly. A good choice if you learn abstract algebra anyway is to look into

- Paolo Aluffi, Chapter 0

It is a book which aims to combine abstract algebra with category theory. Another very good book is

- Emily Riehl, Categories in Context

It contains many examples from different fields of mathematics, in particular also from abstract algebra. You will have it a lot easier in abstract algebra when you understand the Yoneda-lemma, universal properties and adjunctions very well. For the start there is no need to learn anything more specialised, and you also do not have to learn any of the theorems like the monadicity theorem, or the special adjoint functor theorem. Just being able to comfortably prove statements by chasing hom-sets is worth a lot.

Comment: Hey, so I started Aluffi and ordered Riehl based on this comment. Thank you for the suggestion. I guess I can just refer to nlab for the definitions I'm not yet familiar with?

Comment: @user1167466 the nLab articles have a very uneven level of hardness, so do not get frustrated when you do not understand some. categories in context is also freely available online! you can also ask questions here, when you need help :) good luck